# Matlab: Append unique strings into one cell with comma seperation

Tags: string, matlab, loops, append, concatenation

My input is N unique strings of different length stored in a structure such as

```
A.data{1} = {'The cat has'}
A.data{2} = {'green eyes'}
```

such that A.data is Nx1.

The desired output is a 1,1 cell with all the unique strings following each other and separated by commas.

```
output = ['The cat has' ', ' 'green eyes']
```

which produces `The cat has, green eyes` which is exactly what I want for my N strings.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strjoin`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
A.data{1} = 'The cat has';
A.data{2} = 'green eyes';
result = strjoin(A.data, ', ');
```

gives

```
result =
The cat has, green eyes
```

---

If the data has an extra nesting level:

```
A.data{1} = {'The cat has'}
A.data{2} = {'green eyes'};
```

you need to get rid of it with

```
B = cellfun(@(x) x, A.data);
```

before calling `strjoin`:

```
result = strjoin(B, ', ');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strangely enough I get an error message on my own data: "First input must be a cell array of character arrays". This is despite a `whos` returning cell as the type. My specific data looks like `"/dir/file1.extention,1", " /dir/file1.extention,2" ..." /dir/file1.extention,N."`

Comment: Can you edit the question with a variable that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Luis. I've edited the question such that it reproduces the error. I've noticed that my data rather `'The cat has'` and not `The cat has`. Such that the data is written in curly brackets `{ }'.